# Windows remote controle for dual monitor setup

Tags: windows, remote-access, monitors

as mentioned in some other questions plenty of remote control tools [remote-support-tool](https://serverfault.com/questions/155/best-windows-remote-support-screen-sharing-tools)

There are some other options but i often run into the same obstacle

I have a dual monitor setup and the computers i need to remote control ( to assist the people at the other side)  often have a dual monitor setup too.

But all solution i have seen sofar always fail in using both screens. When remote controling i always end up with only 1 monitor used and only 1 monitor controlled

Is there any solution free or paying that is smart in remote controlling with multiple monitor setup ?

Answer (score 9):

RDP version 6.0 and above support using multiple monitors. To use it you have to use the /span command when running it, so to do so from the command line would be:

```
mstsc.exe /v serverIP /span
```

There is a good article [here](http://tech.norabble.com/2006/07/dual-monitor-remote-desktop-goodness.html) on how to setup shortcuts to do this

Comment: I've been using Start, Run, mstsc /w:2560 /h:1024 /v:"server" for a while now.  It's one large desktop, but worth it if you need the space.  I didn't know about the /span option until now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think RDP 6.0 directly supports multiple monitors...  Instead it uses the /span option that allows you to have one large monitor on the remote machine which spans across several local monitors.  Hopefully they all have the same vertical resolution.  To support this configuration, the best tool I've found but not tried is [SplitView](http://www.diskview.com/blog/2007/02/21/multiple-monitors-with-remote-desktop-and-splitview/)

Answer (score 1):

I've used LogMeIn and it has a dual monitor feature. If you have dual monitor you can see one or you click on a button on the top and it switches to the other monitor. This is what I use to remote at home and seem my PC.

Comment: I agree with Hondalex, logmein.com is free, and support multiple monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop supports dual screens.

Answer (score 0):

RDP - aka remote desktop should work
VNC should work with some config tweaking
NX Server either the free one (freeNX) or the other one: Nomachine's NX server should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I think GotoMeeting can do dual monitors, if I recall correctly.  They have a free trial and lots of other cool features too like recording what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Gotomypc has supported dual monitors for the last few versions.  It works pretty well but is expensive compared to the free version of logmein.