# Video conferencing and screensharing options for Windows

Tags: local-area-network, p2p, screen-sharing

We are in need of conferencing solution for our Windows network. Due to security restrictions, the traffic all needs to stay within our LAN. The conferences would all be small and a peer-to-peer architecture is preferred over needing to install and maintain yet another server application. So far, we've ruled out the following options:

- Sype, Yugma, etc. - These would be ideal, but they send traffic outside our LAN through 3rd party servers
- netmeeting - Poor video quality and soon to be deprecated
- Windows Meeting Space - no audio/video

Is there anything else we should look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Office Communications Server 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/communicationsserver/en/us/default.aspx) This will keep the traffic inside the firewall and give you pretty good A/V conferences.  Rough pricing (depending on your discount) should be in the $500 for the server and $25 per user- retail pricing can be found on the website.  I know your question posed the requirement of peer to peer rather than server based but as an admin I'd much rather maintain a single server instance rather than n-number of installations (especially if it ends up being installed company wide)

Comment: Wish I could upvote this multiple times. It can be a major headache to get set up that could have you cursing uncontrollably, but OCS 2007 is the best product out there for IM / Videoconference / Screen Sharing all in one on Windows networks.

Comment: Does Standard edition support multi-person video conferencing, or is that only available in Enterprise?

Comment: yes but you might want to add on a 3rd party video conferencing package depending on your needs or maybe a roundtable device

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Windows communication server also provides Communicator - a msn-like window for chatting within your LAN.  Also has things like whiteboard sharing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

OCS sounds like a good alternative for what you're looking for, specially if you already have MS infrastructure.  That said, I've been wanting to look at [**Ekiga**](http://ekiga.org/) (*Open-source) which would also keep calls inside your LAN, plus have the ability to drop in a **gatekeeper** in case you need need to make or receive off-net video/audio calls.

[**Download Link for Windows**](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Windows_Users)

[alt text http://ekiga.org/images/ekiga_3.png](http://ekiga.org/images/ekiga_3.png)

Ekiga's documentation: [**http://ekiga.org/documentation/ekiga.pdf**](http://ekiga.org/documentation/ekiga.pdf)

For screen sharing, take a look at this question: [**https://serverfault.com/questions/155/best-windows-remote-support-screen-sharing-tools**](https://serverfault.com/questions/155/best-windows-remote-support-screen-sharing-tools)

Comment: I don't know if ekiga will keep *all* the traffic in the LAN; you might need a registration server at the bare minimum. I'm not sure.