# What software is out there for Video Conferencing within our LAN

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, microsoft-office, ms-office-communicator, lync

We are looking at various Video Conferencing tools to have conferences mainly between two offices.  There is a 10mibt connection directly from one to the other and both offices are on the same network.

The web-based software we have tried usually reduces the quality of the video feed and we'd like to use something like Office Communications Server 2007, but not sure about that $3,999 price tag.

Does the standard version support multi-party video conferences, or is that a feature only found in the enterprise version?

Are there other software packages that do the same thing?

Comment: where did you find a pricetag of 4k for OCS?

Comment: The pricetag was 3.999k, according to the OP.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/communicationsserver/en/us/pricing-licensing.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question, Yes OCS2007 Standard supports Video Conferencing.

The main advantage to going with Enterprise is that you can separate the various services to different servers to spread the load.  Eg A/V can be handled on a different server than your Front End pool.

Answer (score 2):

[**Polycom PVX**](http://www.polycom.com/products/telepresence_video/video_conference_systems/personal_systems/pvx.html)

Polycom offers their H.323/SIP (standards-based) software solution for video-conferencing.  Their license is about $120-140 depending on where you get it.  Specially if you're in the same LAN, implementing shouldn't be a big issue.  You can also control what kind of bandwidth capacity you want to use for the call (i.e., 387K, 512K, 768K, 1Mb).  I'm not sure if the current version allows you to do HD or not, but the quality is pretty good (supports H.264).

---

I answered a question about video conferencing [**here:**](https://serverfault.com/questions/50510/video-conferencing-and-screensharing-options-for-windows/50538#50538).

---

[**Ekiga**](http://ekiga.org/)

(*Open-source, Windows, H.323/SIP standards-based) allows you to make calls inside your LAN and supports HD video.  It is an open source SoftPhone, Video Conferencing and Instant Messenger application over the Internet. It supports HD sound quality and video up to DVD size and quality.  It is interoperable with many other standard compliant softwares, hardwares and service providers as it uses both the major telephony standards (SIP and H.323).

[**Windows download link**](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Windows_Users)

Ekiga's documentation: [**http://ekiga.org/documentation/ekiga.pdf**](http://ekiga.org/documentation/ekiga.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to www.nefsis.com and download free 14 day trial.

This is the best multi party video solution in the market. It is hardware agnostic so use whatever video input device you want and the software will support up to HD resolutions.